# How Java EJB injection works with multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, servlets, dependency-injection, ejb

Following the link [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/servlet-30/ejb-injection-in-servlet-fixed-in-jboss-as-5). I understand (or not) that you can inject an **EJB** using the @EJB annotation inside a servlet. A servlet is created with the assumption that it will be run multithread. An EJB however(except singleton) are created in the assumption that only one thread will use it at any one time. But the injection in servlet is done on the member of the servlet class, which means that multiple thread on the servlet may access the member concurrently causing the EJB to have more than one thread at the same time. So how do this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you inject a stateless beans you are safe.

In reality what you inject into the Servlet is a stub & not a real reference. When the stub is invoked by the servlet, the call is delegated to a container managed pooled instance. Hence concurrent calls would be processed by different ejb instances even though it is the same stub.

EJBs themselves are thread-safe

Comment: Any idea how do they implement the stub?

Comment: This should be container specific, have a look at dynamic proxying

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp08305/